# How to use js code to forward reactjs-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-redux

when u seem to require forward in reactjs we used to put a Link or button ,and then consumer click it ,then the page reload corresponding path of router . Now,I want the page turn to other path of router when I request a post and the status of response is 200. It can't use a link or button ,could reactjs use code to do this? like : CertainComponent.setPath(otherPath); CertainComponent.turn;
My English is poor , it may be not clear to delive the function which i want to do.
Thanks！

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use this.context.router.push('/users/12')

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#routercontext

Answer (score 0):

First of all the component you are using has to be a container, which means you have to create it with connect() so it has access on store and dispatch:

```
let MyComponent = ({ dispatch, store }) => {

    store.routing.push('url');
}

export default connect()(MyComponent)
```

And this depends how you named the router key on your store when you combined the routing reducer from **redux-router** on your store.

There is also another alternative, where you could do

```
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router';

hashHistory.push('next-url');
```

Comment: yes ,i have solved this problem ,and i find that i can import hashHistory everywhere and use it(our corporation use redux ,i use it in action). Thank for your help !